# The system cannot find the file specified in RStudio

Tags: r, save, rstudio

I receive this error message almost every time that I type something in the current r script that I am working on.

[image: Photo of Error Message]

The error message continues to pop up until I press Control + S multiple times before the R script can save. Then, about 10-15 seconds later after I type something else, the error message pops up again.

Anyone has a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that you worked on a script in RStudio and saved the script into a certain folder, then you moved the script to a different folder, while still leaving it open in RStudio.

Try closing all scripts in RStudio, then reopening the script (assuming that you’re sure that the script is saved and you know the location it is saved).

Comment: Yes, I believe I tried to the save the file in another folder once. I closed the script in RStudio, closed RStudio, and reopened the script and have not encountered the problem since.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that worked for me was I manually created a folder and the error was resolved.